# How do I find duplicates in a Pandas DataFrame but exclude subjects that are duplicated with themselves in addition to excluding unique values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For example, if my DataFrame has the columns "Date", "Hour", and "Temp", how could I find Hours on Dates with the same Temp while excluding duplicates that occur only on the same Date? I have looked into using the "merge" function, but I'm hoping to avoid using it if possible, since when I tried it, my computer refused to create so large a DataFrame. I could potentially iterate over the rows, but I am hoping there is a more "Pandas" way to do this.

Below is an example of the data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2023/1/1', '2023/1/1', '2023/1/2', '2023/1/2', '2023/1/2'],
    'Hour': ['0600', '1800', '0600', '1200', '1800'],
    'Temp': [40, 40, 40, 50, 50]
})
df
```

```
       Date  Hour  Temp
0  2023/1/1  0600    40
1  2023/1/1  1800    40
2  2023/1/2  0600    40
3  2023/1/2  1200    50
4  2023/1/2  1800    50
```

This command doesn't quite do what I want it to do:

```
df[df.duplicated(subset=['Temp'], keep=False) & ~df.duplicated(subset=['Date','Temp'], keep=False)]
```

The output is:

```
       Date  Hour  Temp
2  2023/1/2  0600    40
```

But I would like to output:

```
       Date  Hour  Temp
0  2023/1/1  0600    40
1  2023/1/1  1800    40
2  2023/1/2  0600    40
```

Where the duplicated Temp on 2023/1/2 is excluded because it is only shared on that Date, but the duplicated Temp on 2023/1/1 is included because it is also shared with another Date.

Please let me know if this is a duplicate question or if more information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with help of [`groupby.transform('nunique')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
# is a value present in more than 1 date?
m1 = df.groupby('Temp')['Date'].transform('nunique').gt(1)
# is a value non-duplicated?
m2 = ~df['Temp'].duplicated(keep=False)

# keep if either condition is True
out = df[m1|m2]
```

Output:

```
       Date  Hour  Temp
0  2023/1/1  0600    40
1  2023/1/1  1800    40
2  2023/1/2  0600    40
```

Comment: isn't m1 condition sufficient?

Comment: The provided example is unclear to this extent, it depends what OP really wants to do. For example of there was a new row with a unique Temp and date, should it be kept or dropped? ;)

Comment: Any unique Temps should not be included in the query. Does that clear up the confusion?

Comment: @Keethan then only use `m1`, you might want to update your title ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach is to count "Temp" occurences for distinct "Date"s. Later just filter all rows where the number of occurences is bigger than 1.

In first step just group by "Temp" and count number of unique "Date"s it is found for:

```
df['temp_occs_for_dist_dates'] = df.groupby(["Temp"])["Date"].transform('nunique')
```

and later simply filter for rows with "temp_occs_for_dist_dates" bigger than 1.

```
df = df[df["temp_occs_for_dist_dates"] > 1 ]
```

and in the end you can clean up and delete new column

```
df = df.drop(columns=["temp_occs_for_dist_dates"])
```

I hope I understood correctly and this solution will be helpful :)